# pthread_setschedparam returns EPERM when called from native code in android jelly bean

Tags: android, apk, root, policy, native-code

I just started studying Android programming and trying some sample application to explore more in android. Currently I am looking to change the thread policy of a thread that is created from native code in android. I am giving the request to change the thread policy from android application and it will pass the new thread policy to native code and native application will call pthread_setschedparam() to change the native thread policy. But pthread_setschedparam() returned EPERM error. 
From my understanding, this error is returned due to the permission issue (root access). Is my understanding correct? 
If this is the case, how can I resolve the issue?
I made some search and found that to resolve this issue, I need to root the device and use some application like SuperUser to give root access to the android application. But now I am working in a non-rooted device. Is it possible to resolve this issue in non-rooted device?
Thanks for the help in advance.